# htaccess rewrite rule for query string redirect?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My htaccess block of code in wordpress works fine but I can't understand the syntax despite knowing what it does.

```html
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "mobileSite=" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]
```

For example a url as follows

> www.example.com/?mobileSite=1

will be redirected to

> www.example.com

The code works fine but I cant understand the actual syntax part. For example what does `(.*)  /$1? [R=301,L]` do?

There number after `mobileSite` is a variable between 0 and 1 but it is not included in `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "mobileSite=" [NC]` despite the code actually working.

Please explain to me the syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match only `0` or `1` in query parameter then use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mobileSite=[01]$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

**`RewriteRule` Breakup:**

```
(.*)  # match anything in URI and group it in captured group #1
/$1   # $1 is back-reference of captured value in (.*)
R=301 # redirect with status 301
L     # Last rule
?     # ? in the end is for stripping any previous query string
```

**`RewriteCond` Breakup:**

```
%{QUERY_STRING} # match from query string
^               # start
mobileSite=[01] # match mobileSite=0 or mobileSite=1
$               # end
[NC]            # flag for ignore case
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)
- [.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php)